# How do I bring back lost Kerbals?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I did a bad thing - I shot Jebediah at Kerbin at 20,000m/s. The chute didn't even slow him down and he impacted at Mach 4.

He's now listed as **MIA** under the **Lost** tab. How do I bring him back to life?

I don't really want to start a new game...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Sandbox Mode, Kerbals don't *die*. They "mysteriously disappear".

They respawn after a short while (the original three (Jebediah, Bill, Bob) at a quicker rate than generic Kerbals), and can then be sent to their doom again. And again. And again.

Comment: Any idea how long it takes for them to respawn?

Comment: @Coomie Some people report a couple of days, other a couple of weeks (ingame time, that is) ... I haven't had time to analyze it more closely yet, sorry.

Answer (score 12):

If you want them back to life *immediately* rather than waiting, you can open your `KSP game folder/saves/username/persistent.sfs` with your favorite text editor, find `ROSTER` and change the crew members' statuses from `state = 3` to `state = 0`. This will instantly revive your Kerbals.

I'm not sure if it matters whether the game is running or not, but I would make sure and edit the file while the game is **not** running.

[Source on KSP forums](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/showthread.php/41974-damn-how-can-i-save-edit-to-revive-the-dead)

Comment: I'd recommend not edited the persistent file during gameplay; the game's still in alpha, and it may cause corruption.

Comment: @3ventic I did this and it worked but it's not the most correct answer. But I'll give you a vote up.

Answer (score 2):

if you open the debug toolbar and go and open your debug toolbar using alt + f12 and you go to the gameplay tab from there you can enable wether or wether not your kerbals to respawn or not too, and if you would like to bring them back to life immediately you can go to your "saves" folder in your ksp directory go to persistent.sfs file in one of your saves then you just turn the dead kerbal's state from state = 3 to state = 0.

edit: actually the states you can choose are not 0 or 3 they are now:
**state = available** 
as alive or 
**state = dead**.

Answer (score 1):

An update to [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/127988/159338)

First, this is highly suggested as it is hard to tell what effects it may have on the game, to close KSP.

Open the persistent.sfs file. It is located at `ksp base folder/saves/savename/persistent.sfs`

Find(CTRL+F on windows) `ROSTER` and locate the crew member. Change `state = Dead` to `state = Available`. Save the file.

Reload KSP and load the game as usual.

This can be useful when (with respawn available in career, science or sandbox) the respawn doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the respawning the original 3 takes only a hour in real time. I did this and Jeb, Bill, and Bob were all killed going to the mun, and I built another a hour later and they were all on it somehow.